# Finite groups with all maximal subgroups of prime power index are solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

It is well known that in finite solvable groups, any maximal subgroup has prime power index.

> **Question:** If $G$ is a finite group in which any maximal subgroup has prime power index, is $G$ solvable?

Up to groups of order $<180$, the answer to the question seems to be yes.

Comment: You seem to have missed one of the few, or the only one, known counter examples of order 168, @Marshal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is no. A counterexample is given by the simple group of order $168$ (every maximal subgroup has index $8$ or $7$). Using the classification of finite simple groups, it has been proven by Guralnick [1] that this is the only example of a finite nonabelian simple group with this property.

There is a partial converse due to Philip Hall, which states the following

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $G$ is a finite group and that for any maximal subgroup $M$, the index $[G:M]$ is prime or a square of a prime. Then $G$ is solvable.

A proof can be found in *Endliche Gruppen* by Huppert, pg. 718, Satz VI.9.4. Also in *A Course on Group Theory* by Rose, pg. 281, Theorem 11.16 and *The Theory of Groups* by M. Hall, pg. 161, Theorem 10.5.7.

There is also the following result due to Huppert (1954):

> **Theorem:** A finite group $G$ is supersolvable if and only if every maximal subgroup of $G$ has prime index.

Proof: Suppose that $G$ is supersolvable and let $M$ be a maximal subgroup. Now there exists a normal subgroup $P$ of prime order. If $P \leq M$, then $M/P$ is a maximal subgroup of the supersolvable group $G/P$, and the result follows by induction. Otherwise $P \cap M = 1$, and in this case $G = PM$ since $M$ is maximal. In particular $[G:M] = |P|$.

For the other direction, a proof is in *Endliche Gruppen* by Huppert, pg. 718, Satz VI.9.5, and also in *Group Theory* by Scott, pg. 226, Theorem 9.3.8 and *The Theory of Groups* by M. Hall, pg. 162, Theorem 10.5.8.

[1] R. Guralnick, *Subgroups of prime power index in a simple group*, Journal of Algebra, Volume 81, Issue 2, April 1983, Pg. 304–311 [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693%2883%2990190-4)

Comment: Unless its proof is  too long and complicated,Can you give proof or some refference.

Comment: Thansk for edit.

Comment: In his book "A course in Group Theory" (page 279,immediately after corollary 11.15), John S. Rose mentions that precisely that simple group of order $\;168\;,\;\;GL_3(\Bbb Z_2)\;$ ,  is the *only* **known** example of non-soluble group all of which maximal subgroups have index a power of a prime (as mentioned above, $\;7\,,\,8\;$).  The book's from 1978, a little before Guralnick's paper.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Right, that's how I first found out about this example. Also, I think you mean non-soluble *simple* group.

Comment: Yes @MikkoKorhonen. In fact, Rose's mentions "non abelian **simple** group", without *non -soluble*, thus leaving open the door for some other potentially non-soluble non-simple finite group...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think something like $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_2) \times C_p$, with $p > 7$ prime should be an example.

Comment: Good one, @MikkoKorhonen. Undoubtedly that is a non-solvable non-simple group.+1