# Does every nontrivial finite group have a subgroup of prime index?

Tags: group-theory

I know that a finite group need not have a subgroup for any particular prime index (for example, $A_4$ has no subgroup of index $2$, but it does have one of index $3$). Is there a nontrivial finite group with no subgroups of prime index?

Comment: The trivial group.

Comment: Thanks, edited. I should have seen that myself...

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420530/ for a stronger (but false) claim, and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694836/ for a closer-to-true claim. Both are answered by the same paper of Guralnick, but might be interesting questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple group $\operatorname{PSL}(2,8)$ has no subgroup of prime index. Its maximal subgroups have indices 9, 28, and 36.

In general $\operatorname{PSL}(2,q)$ has order $q(q-1)(q+1)/\gcd(q-1,2)$. Set $d=\gcd(q-1,2)$.

It has (usually) maximal subgroups that are dihedral of order $2(q+1)/d$ and $2(q-1)/d$. It has a maximal subgroup of order $q(q-1)/d$. If $q$ is a power of $r$ (with the power itself prime), then $\operatorname{PSL}(2,r)$ is a (usually) maximal subgroup. It also has (usually) maximal subgroups of orders $12$, $24$, or $60$ ($A_4$, $S_4$, or $A_5$ depending on some congruences on $q$).

For $q=8$, we get the order is 504. It has no subgroup of order 60 by Lagrange. So we check the (possibly) maximal subgroups of order $2(q+1)/d = 18$, $2(q-1)/d = 14$, $q(q-1)/d = 56$, $2(2-1)(2+1)/\gcd(2-1,2) = 6$ (not maximal in this exceptional case), and $24$ (which in this exceptional case is contained in the order 56 group).

These subgroups have index 28, 36, 9, 84, and 21.

The subgroup classification is in Huppert's *Endliche Gruppen* Kap II. §8, pages 191-214, culminating in Dickson's Hauptsatz 8.26 on page 213 (which is just the more precise version of what I said above).

---

Most simple groups have no subgroups of even prime *power* index. The list of exceptions is fairly short and is given in Guralnick (1983). In particular, the cyclic groups of prime order, a few bizarre PSL(n,q), alternating groups of prime power degree, the prime degree Mathieu groups, and PSp(4,3). Every other simple group is a counterexample to the claim that a non-identity group must have some proper subgroup of prime power index. For example the alternating group $A_{6} = \operatorname{PSL}(2,9)$ has maximal subgroup indices 6, 6, 10, 15, and 15.

- Guralnick, Robert M.
  [“Subgroups of prime power index in a simple group.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(83)90190-4)
  J. Algebra 81 (1983), no. 2, 304–311.
  MR[700286](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=700286)

Comment: Can you provide a reference or an argument for this?

Comment: I can write it up. Burnside and Dickson circa 1910 textbooks have a  description of all subgroups of PSL(2,q).

Comment: Here is one positive result: if $G$ is a nontrivial finite solvable group, then some subgroup of $G$ has prime index. (proof: use induction)

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: slightly stronger (from @lhf) if $G$ is finite but not perfect, then $G/G'$ has a subgroup of prime index, so $G$ does as well.